# Hide password in python using getpass.getpass()

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, passwords, sha

When I type

```
>>> passwd = getpass.getpass()
```

Into the python 2.7 shell, in IDLE, I get the result:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/getpass.py", line 55
    passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Password:
```

Then when I type the password, it isn't hidden. I need to send it to a variable, so I can SHA it using the sha module and compare it with the 'SHAed' original.

Comment: Are you running it in idle? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264701/getpass-getpass-error-without-other-code

Comment: Also, pass is a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass is a python keyword . please change that something like

```
password = getpass.getpass()
```

Then run it from shell/console