# How can I prevent echoing of the password in macbook version of Python?

Tags: python

I'm using the getpass module for hiding the password while the user types it, but...

[image: This happens..]

How can I prevent this?
I may be asking a stoopid question, but I'm new to python so help me out if you can guys!

Thanks.

Comment: Which terminal are you using? [It has been reported not to work in IDLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264701/getpass-getpass-error-without-other-code)

Comment: I'm using IDLE. Is there any way to use the macbook terminal to run the program?

Comment: @euphoria Of course you can run the program using a mac terminal. Open a terminal, `cd` to where the program/python file is, then run `python your_program.py`