# Is there any way i can make an input line dissappear after inputing? Python

Tags: python

i am creating a rock, paper, scissors game for 2 PLAYERS. However, when the first player enters rock, paper or scissors, i want their input to vanish so then the second player can then enter theirs. Becuase i dont want them seeing each others entries. Is this possible in Python 3.5.0 ?
any help would be much appreciated!
thanks!
i do not want to clear the whole screen, just ONE line!

Comment: I would probably use `sys.stdout.write` if the input is allowed to be visible as it is typed but should disappear after the user presses enter. If you want it to be replaced by `*` *while* the user types - like in a real password prompt - there are differences between linux and windows that need to be considered (I haven't found a simple way of evaluating input without pressing enter in linux - only by importing pygame which seems excessive. On windows, it's easier. Getpass might be the simplest cross-platform solution in this case). What are your exact requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html), which is normally used for entering passwords, so the user's input is not printed to the terminal.

Here's an example of running this in the interpreter, the text 'Rock' that I entered at the prompt was not shown, but is available in the 'choice' variable.

```
>>> import getpass
>>> choice = getpass.getpass("Rock/Paper/Scissors:")
Rock/Paper/Scissors:
>>> choice
'Rock'
>>>
```

You'd want to put this in a loop which checked that the user had entered one of the valid options, so you'd have something like:

```
import getpass

valid_options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
valid_choice = False
while (not valid_choice):
    choice = getpass.getpass("Rock/Paper/Scissors:")
    if (choice in valid_options):
        valid_choice = True
    else:
        print("Invalid option. Please try again")
```

Comment: How would i go about adding that to my code, couyld you give an example, say with the input, rock, paper or scissors and then your funtion?
thanks!

Comment: I've added an example of getting the user's option and checking it is one of the valid options.

Comment: I entered that, but i get this error.:

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\getpass.py", line 101
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Rock/Paper/Scissors:

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264701/getpass-getpass-error-without-other-code) - are you using IDLE? Running in cmd.exe or Windows PowerShell is recommended to avoid this problem (code above runs fine on my linux machine).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an escape sequence:

```
valid = ("rock", "paper", "scissors")
choice = input("What is your choice? ").lower()
while choice not in valid:
    print("\033[1A\033[K", end="")
    choice = input("Invalid choice.  Try again: ").lower()
print("\033[1A\033[K", end="")
```