# Trouble with masking password input in Python

Tags: python, passwords, getpass

I am using Python. I am making a script where the user has to enter the password in the terminal.

I have already found a solution on this website by using the getpass module.

```
new_password=getpass.getpass(prompt="Type new password: ")
```

The problem is I get a warning and the password input gets displayed as well.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\getpass.py", line 101
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
```

Comment: `getpass.win_getpass()` for widows use this.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't help

Comment: are you using IDLE or windows terminal?

Comment: I am using IDLE

Comment: IDLE has issue with the stdout and stderr, try to use the normal terminal
[question-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878741/getpasswarning-can-not-control-echo-on-the-terminal-when-running-from-idle);  [question-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264701/getpass-getpass-error-without-other-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal" when running from IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878741/getpasswarning-can-not-control-echo-on-the-terminal-when-running-from-idle)

Answer (score 1):

Use command prompt as admin to run this program.

Reason is because system environment where stdin, stdout and stderr are connected to /dev/tty, or another PTY-compliant device.

The IDLE REPL does not meet this requirement.

And change `new_password=getpass.getpass(prompt="Type new password: ")` to `new_password=getpass.getpass("Type new password: ")` if you are using Windows OS or `new_password=getpass.getpass("Type new password: ", None)` for Linux distributions.

This would help you for sure:

```
import getpass
pw = getpass.getpass("Enter Your Password Here: ")
if pw == "password":
    print("You are Welcome...")
else:
    print("Sorry! You're are not allowed.")
```

As per Python documentation:

`getpass.getpass([prompt[, stream]])`

Prompt the user for a password without echoing. The user is prompted using the string prompt, which defaults to 'Password: '. On Unix, the prompt is written to the file-like object stream. stream defaults to the controlling terminal (/dev/tty) or if that is unavailable to sys.stderr (this argument is ignored on Windows)

Changed in version 2.5: The stream parameter was added.

**Note:** If you call getpass from within IDLE, the input may be done in the terminal you launched IDLE from rather than the idle window itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using a normal terminal with this code:

```
import getpass
new_password=getpass.getpass(prompt="Type new password: ")
print(new_password)
```

Will work alright, but if we try the same with IDLE we'll get the error you've exposed in your question.

Now, if we look at the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html) you'll see this is intended, it says:

> Note If you call getpass from within IDLE, the input may be done in
>   the terminal you launched IDLE from rather than the idle window
>   itself.