Getpass() not working in Pycharm IDE, emulate terminal in output console option not working either. Any solution?
I'm trying to run some code in which I need the getpass() function to accept a password confidentially. Currently, only input("Enter the password") is working. When I use getpass, it does say "Enter the password", accepts an input which isn't hidden, and you can't enter/submit it. The code gets stuck at that point.
I DID try emulating the terminal output into the console. This didn't work either.
Any ideas as to how to resolve this?
Since getpass() is an inbuilt python library, I expected it to work fine. I also tried using passwordbox() from the easygui library, same issue again.

Please include your code. It may be the reason why your question is getting downvoted.

Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160698/trouble-with-masking-password-input-in-python?rq=1  Unfortunately, I think the OS makes a difference.

In the run configuration, I checked "Emulate terminal in output console". Then, and only then, did the following code run correctly (printing the password prompt):
import getpass

username = input("username: ")
password = getpass.getpass("password: ")

if password == "1234":
    print("password entered successfully")

I'm using Pycharm 2022.1.2 (Community Edition) and Python 3.12.3 on a Windows OS.
